# Unity2D: Scaling image in scene window

Tags: unity-game-engine, scaling

I have this script:

```
public Sprite[] Images; //Index starts at one because we are setting the first sprite in Start() method
public int _Index = 1;
public float width;
public float height;


void Start(){
    //Set the image to the first one
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[0];
}

public void onClick(){
    //Reset back to 0 so it can loop again if the last sprite has been shown
    if (_Index >= Images.Length)
        _Index = 0;

    //Set the image to array at element index, then increment
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[_Index++];
}
```

that works perfectly, what it does is that it changes the image of and object OnClick once all images has been shown it loops. However I can't scale my images manually in my scene window nor through script. Is there an easier way of changing my script to be able to manually scaling my images in my scene window. (I would rather scale my images in my scene window rather than through script because I would find it easier) Please and thank you :)

**Second Edit**
This is what my script looks like now:

```
public Sprite[] Images;
//Index starts at one because we are setting the first sprite in Start() method
public int _Index = 1;
public float width;
public float height;
public float lastWidth;
public float lastHeight;

void ResizeMe()
{
    this.width = 1.567892f;
    this.height = 1.07f;
}

void Update()
{
    if(this.width != lastWidth || this.height != lastHeight)
    {
        ResizeMe (this.width, this.height);
        this.lastWidth = width;
        this.lastHeight = height;
    }
}

void Start(){
    //Set the image to the first one
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[0];
}

public void onClick(){
    //Reset back to 0 so it can loop again if the last sprite has been shown
    if (_Index >= Images.Length)
        _Index = 0;

    //Set the image to array at element index, then increment
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[_Index++];
}
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

declare 2 more variables
lastWidth
lastHeight

in the Update() function do something like

```
if(this.width != lastWidth || this.height != lastHeight)
{
    setSize(this.width,this.height)
    this.lastWidth = width;
    this.lastHeight = height;
}
```

create a setSize function to do the actual resizing.
Now when you change the public width,height variables from the editor the update will pick on the change and run your resize script

Comment: thank you for the reply but I'm getting this error: error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `this'. It links back to  this.lastWidth = width;

Comment: @Bakausagi-chan You have to put `;` after `setSize(this.width,this.height)`. FYI, you really need to start accepting answers if they solved your problem. It is a way of saying thank you. You get so much help on SO but you don't seem to accept any of them even those that seems to have solved your problem.

Comment: Uh sorry about this again but now i'm getting this error:  The member `Spritechange.setSize' cannot be used as method or delegate

Comment: post your setSize code.
If there is already a setSize member then change the function name to something else like ResizeMe or something and do the resizing there.
I cant open a project at the moment to provide a guaranteed working sample :S

Comment: I think I just made setSize as a float.

Comment: because I got this error before: The name `setSize' does not exist in the current context

Comment: what do you mean you made it float?

man write this

public void ResizeMe(float wd,float hgt)
{
// in here assign the sizes to where they should go
// like this.width = wd and this.height=hgt
// or something similar, i have not worked with sprites for a while
}

and call this function on the update instead of my previous SetSize

Comment: Hi, no sorry but now I got this error: error CS1501: No overload for method `ResizeMe' takes `2' arguments. Please look at my second edit to have a look at what my script looks like now. Thank you for your reply. :)